# nodejs not redirecting in post

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I'm currently playing around with node.js, express, and jade and can't figure out why it won't redirect when I use a jQuery POST. I read around and it seems this is a known bug but can't figure out anyway around it. Here is my code for reference:

backend code:

```
app.get('/ace', function (req, res) {
  res.render('ace', {test: 4});
});

app.post('/ace', function (req, res) {
  var input = req.body.submittedInput;
  console.log(input);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

frontend (in jade)

```
script
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var session = editor.getSession();
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // Use jQuery in here
  $("#submitButton").click(function() {
  $.post("/ace", 
  { "submittedInput": session.getLines(0, session.getLength()-1)},
    "json");
  });
 });
button(type='button', id="submitButton")
 | SUBMIT
```

and here is the console output

```
[ '//Begin Typing Code here', '4' ]
POST /ace 302 5ms - 35
GET / 200 59ms - 12.54kb
```

Comment: I don't see the problem: As your output says it receives the post request and sends a redirect (status code 302). After that it receives a get request on /, which is exactely the target you set (res.redirect('/')). So the redirect works. What's the problem?

Comment: Your output is showing that it got redirected to `/`, what is the issue?

Comment: I'm getting the correct status code, but the page is not redirecting. It is staying at '/ace' and not going to '/'

Comment: naturally, because you're using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a misunderstanding how what exactly the code you have written does:

```
$.post(
  "/ace",
  { "submittedInput": session.getLines(0, session.getLength()-1)},
  "json"
);
```

This sends a POST request to `/ace`, but your redirect will only effect this specific request, it does not effect the whole browser session. What you have now is essentially the same as if you removed the redirect line and instead did a second `$.post` request to `/` after the first request completed.

If you want to redirect the browser itself, then you would need to remove your `redirect` line and instead send back some JSON containing the target URI or something. Then your jQuery code would read that code and redirect the page itself.